# Is there any disadvantage to selling a Bobblehead or a magazine in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4 the Bobbleheads are back.

Once you pick them up they stay in your inventory with a weight of 0 and a value of 300. Will I need them later ? Do I lose the bonus if I sell them or drop them somewhere ? Same with the magazines.

**Is there any disadvantage to selling them ?**

Comment: You can build a bobblehead stand in your settlement to display them.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You won't lose the bonus once you find them, but you will miss out on the awesome opportunity to display them in your home, also its way easier to keep track of which bobblehead you've found already if you still have them.

You can build a magazine rack (2 kinds actually) and bobblehead display station if you have the materials that are especially designed to hold those items.

Comment: Pretty sure I've never seen either option in my build screen, though I've seen and used the Bobblehead display at a certain non-settlement player home. Is there a specific item required to unlock these?

Comment: I might just be missing something. Everywhere I've Googled says to go under Furnituare -> Misc, without any pre-qualification. Will double-check next chance I get.

Comment: @Iszi I think the bobblehead thing *is* under misc, but I'd need to doublecheck. The magazine rack is under shelves. There's at least one spinning one, and at least one that is more like a shelf.

Comment: @DCShannon Found the bobblehead display and the magazine racks last night. I love that they act like containers *and* display what you put in them. Like the weapon racks in Skyrim.

Comment: Checked last night, and confirmed you can't see the bobblehead perks on your perk page. So, if you don't keep them I think the only way to check which ones you have would be to go to where they are found and see if they have been picked up yet.

Answer (score -4):

I think the little plus symbol next to your SPECIAL attributes in your stats menu represent the bobble heads. I could be wrong but what else would it be.

Comment: You have a little + next to your special stats when they are improved by drugs, food or equipment.