# Where's the bobblehead stand?

Tags: fallout-4

I know it exists, but I haven't yet unlocked it as far as I can see.

How do I unlock the bobblehead (and magazine?!) stand so I can put them in my settlement?

Comment: I thought we already had this question, but it just gets discussed in the comments on [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/242903/108003).

Comment: Answer to title: Wherever you left it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are unlocked by default, you already have them.

Both are in "Furniture". The bobblehead stand is under "Misc", and the magazine racks (there are multiple types) are under "Shelves".

We have an answer that lists each workshop item, the category it is in, and the component cost of each: [What is the component cost of each Workshop item in Fallout 4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/248201/108003).

- Magazine Rack (1 screw, 4 steel) [two variations]
- Bobblehead Stand (3 screws, 4 steel, 3 fiberglass)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to building your own, when you take up residence at Vault 81 there is a bobblehead stand ready and waiting for you.

Comment: I initially downvoted this, then retracted it. I mean, you're not wrong. Also not really answering the question, though. There are premade magazine racks also, including at the red rocket truck stop.

Comment: @DCShannon well the question is "where's the bobblehead stand", there are several possible answers, including yours. I don't believe there's another pre-built bobblehead stand in the game (though I doubt I explored everywhere).

Comment: That may be the title, but it's not the question. In the body they say they want to add them to their settlement, not find one in the world.

Comment: Down-voted for the same reason @DCShannon initially did. Also the reason why I didn't post my comment to the question as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

It is under miscellaneous furniture items